# Show Hide Subnav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I toggle the subnav for each item, and if one is open, hide the open one to show the current one? If there are none shown, just toggle. If you click one and show subnav then and click another hide previous and show current.

Here is my html -

```
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="user-menu-wrapper">
            <div class="hsn-logo"></div>
            <div class="user-greeting-wrapper">
                <div class="user-greeting">Hi, Abraham</div>
            </div>
            <div class="user-menu">
                <ul class="user-menu-items">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "my-account" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "my-favorites" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "my-bag" })</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hsn-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="hsn-nav">
                <ul class="hsn-nav-items">
                    <li style="width: 25%">
                        <a class="shop" href="#">
                            <span class="hsn-nav-item-wrap">
                                <span>SHOP</span><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="width: 25%">
                        <a class="watch" href="#">
                            <span class="hsn-nav-item-wrap">
                                <span>WATCH</span><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="width: 25%">
                        <a class="play" href="#">
                            <span class="hsn-nav-item-wrap">
                                <span>PLAY</span><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span>
                        </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="width: 15%">
                        <a href=""><span class="hsn-search-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br class="clear" />
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<subnav id="shop" class="shop-subnav">
    <div class="hsn-subnav-wrapper">
        <div class="hsn-subnav">
            <div class="hsn-subnav-left">
                <ul>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li><span class="hsn-subnav-callout">Deals</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="hsn-subnav-right">
                <ul>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem</li>
                    <li><span class="hsn-subnav-callout">Clearance</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</subnav>
<subnav id="watch" class="watch-subnav">
    <div class="hsn-subnav-wrapper">
        <div class="hsn-subnav">
            <div class="hsn-subnav-left">
                <ul>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="hsn-subnav-right">
                <ul>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                    <li>SubnavItem2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</subnav>
```

Here is my Jquery / JS -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('ul.hsn-nav-items li a').click(function () {
    var navitem = $(this).attr('id')
        , id = $(this).attr('class')
        , subnav = $('subnav.' + id + '-subnav');
    $('a.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('#'+id).toggle();
});
```

});

Comment: I've never seen a `subnav` element before. Also, you may be able to get the effect you want by just using nested UL elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing through your html - you have duplicate IDs.  Your 'a' that links to 'play' also has an ID of 'play' - that element will be selected, not the subnav!

Also, two of your links are classed watch, none shop.

Comment: Not taking play into account at the moment

Comment: I removed it to save confusion.

Comment: fixed...do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to approach this is to hide all the `<subnav>` on each click. All your existing code will work just fine which already takes care of toggling the relevant `<subnav>`.

```
var $subNavs = $('subnav');
$subNavs.hide();

$('ul.hsn-nav-items li a').click(function () {
    $subNavs.hide();

    var navitem = $(this).attr('id')
        , id = $(this).attr('class')
        , subnav = $('subnav.' + id + '-subnav');
    $('a.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('#'+id).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

​I also added a `return false;` to stop the default click event on the `<a>` being executed, which could result in a page load since `href="#"`.

That said, `<subnav>` is a non-standard element and you would be better off using a simpler markup to describe the data. It may also prove useful to give the each subnav a common class which makes finding them via jQuery simpler.

I have also made a [**small demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4sCJ/) using the following simplified code

HTML

```
<a class="shop" href="#">
    <span class="hsn-nav-item-wrap">
        <span>SHOP</span><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span>
    </span>
</a><br/>
<a class="watch" href="#">
    <span class="hsn-nav-item-wrap">
        <span>WATCH</span><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span>
    </span>
</a><br/>
<a class="play" href="#">
    <span class="hsn-nav-item-wrap">
        <span>PLAY</span><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span>
</span>
</a>
<div id="shop" class="shop subnav">
shop
</div>
<div id="watch" class="watch subnav">
watch
</div>
<div id="play" class="play subnav">
play
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var $subNavs = $('.subnav');
$subNavs.hide();

$('a').click(function () {
    var $subNavToToggle = $('#' + ($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]));
    var doToggle = $subNavToToggle.is(':not(:visible)');
    $subNavs.hide();

    $('a.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    $subNavToToggle.toggle(doToggle);

    return false;
});
```